# How to use fake headers

Tags: python, session

Here is my code:

```
DEVICE = {
'instagram_version': '26.0.0.10.86',
'android_version': 24,
'android_release': '7.0',
'dpi': '640dpi',
'resolution': '1440x2560',
'manufacturer': 'samsung',
'device': 'SM-G930F',
'model': 'herolte',
'cpu': 'samsungexynos8890'
}

USER_AGENT_BASE = (
'Instagram {instagram_version} '
'Android ({android_version}/{android_release}; '
'{dpi}; {resolution}; {manufacturer}; '
'{device}; {model}; {cpu}; en_US)'
)

user_agent = USER_AGENT_BASE.format(**DEVICE)

REQUEST_HEADERS = {'Content-type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8'}

sess = requests.Session()
sess.headers.update(REQUEST_HEADERS)
sess.headers.update({'User-Agent': user_agent})
response = sess.post(LOGIN_URL, data=data)
assert response.status_code == 200
```

Instead of user_agent I need to use module fake_headers to generate random headers. How do i do it?

Answer (score 0):

add it like this :

```py
import urllib.request

REQUEST_HEADERS = {'Content-type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8'}
urllib.request.Request("your link", headers=REQUEST_HEADERS)
```

Comment: @ivan add user agent to the header: ```'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'```